# Output size of mcrypt_encrypt

Tags: php, encryption, base64, mcrypt

I have a table with a field **name**. I want to store name-data as encrypted into the field.
The name can be 128 characters. Then what should be the type of the field (eg: varchar(256) or text).

The following function I am using for encryption/decryption.

```
<?php

$salt ='whatever_you_want';

function simple_encrypt($text) {
    return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
}

function simple_decrypt($text) {
    return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, base64_decode($text), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)));
}
```

Comment: Why not run a few strings of 128 character length through your code, display the maximum size of output and make your field length accordingly?

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ I think there will be some relation between the input+key and output. I fear the experiment won't give accurate output size.

Comment: Yes I agree, but once the key is decided by the programmer it will remain same, otherwise decrypt wont work if the key keeps changing

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ yep, the key size is constant.

Comment: Key size is not directly related to block size actually.

Answer (score 1):

Why not run a few strings of 128 character length through your code, display the maximum size of output and make your field length accordingly? With this existing key, it returns `172` length every time.

```
<?php

function rand_string( $length ) {
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";  

    $size = strlen( $chars );
    for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
        $str .= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
    }

    return $str;
}


$salt ='whatever_you_want';

function simple_encrypt($text) {
    return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
}

function simple_decrypt($text) {
    return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, base64_decode($text), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)));
}



for($i=0;$i<100;$i++)
{
$word=rand_string(128);
$e=simple_encrypt($word);
echo strlen($e)."<br>";
}

?>
```